# read hex at certain position and return the correspond text

Tags: c#, database, hex, extract

```
private void sourceDatabase(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[5];
        reader.BaseStream.Seek(reader.BaseStream.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        reader.Read(buffer, 0, 5);

        string source = "";
        foreach (var item in buffer)
        {
            string temp = "0";
            if (item.ToString("X").Length == 1)
                source += temp + item.ToString("X") + " ";
            else
                source += item.ToString("X") + " ";
        }
        if (source.Length != 0)
            source = source.Substring(0, source.Length - 1);
        MessageBox.Show("File Source : " + source, "Result");

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["databaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = null;
        string ori_source = source;
        //int flag = 1;
        while (true)
        {
            string sql = "SELECT source FROM sourceDatabase WHERE Hexadecimal like '" + source + "%'";
            command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            if (source.Length != 0 && source.Length > 5)
            {
                source = source.Substring(0, source.Length - 1);
                if (command.ExecuteScalar() != null)
                {
                    string scr = System.Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                    //string desc = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("Source : " + scr, "Result");
                    //flag = 2;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else break;
        }
    }
```

When the picture file has been selected, the program will run to scan the header of the file by comparing it with the database provided.

Then it move on to determine the file source of the picture file. The problem is that when I scan the picture file using the system, I cannot locate the source by doing the same like I did on the header.

retrieve the hex code that has the particular format (eg: 40 70 70 6c 65), compare it with database, return the 'source'.